# Cytoscape.js - Circle layout

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I'm trying to make this http://gcuculi.com/cda/imagens/grafico.png with Cytoscape.js. I'm using the circle layout, but it isn't working. I will add more items dynamically. The first node always be closer than the second and so on for the others.

Here is the code:

```
$(function(){ 
  var cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('grafico-constelacao'),

  style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
   .selector('node')
     .css({
       'content': 'data(name)',
       'text-valign' : 'center',
       'color' : 'white',
      })
   .selector('edge')
     .css({
       'width': 2,
       'line-color': '#000'
     })
    .selector('#p')
      .css({
        'background-color': '#fff',
        'width': '60px',
        'height': '60px',
        'border-width': '2px',
        'border-style': 'solid',
        'border-color ': '#888',
      }),

  elements: {

    nodes: [
      {
        data: {id: 'p', weight: 1 },
        group: 'nodes',
        position: {
          x: 500,
          y: 150
        },
        classes: 'principal',
        selected: false,
        selectable: false,
        locked: true,
        grabbable: false
      },
      { data: { id: 'atr1', name : 'A'} },
      { data: { id: 'atr2', name : 'B' } },
      { data: { id: 'atr3', name : 'C' } },
      { data: { id: 'atr4', name : 'D' } },
      { data: { id: 'atr5', name : 'E' } }   
    ], 

    edges: [
      { data: { id: 'p-atr1', weight: 1, source: 'p', target: 'atr1' } },
      { data: { id: 'p-atr2', weight: 10, source: 'p', target: 'atr2' } },
      { data: { id: 'p-atr3', weight: 50, source: 'p', target: 'atr3' } },
      { data: { id: 'p-atr4', weight: 100, source: 'p', target: 'atr4' } },
      { data: { id: 'p-atr5', weight: 250, source: 'p', target: 'atr5' } }
    ]
  },

  layout: {
    name: 'circle',

    fit: true,
    padding: 30, 
    boundingBox: undefined,
    avoidOverlap: true,
    radius: undefined,
    startAngle: 10 * Math.PI,
    counterclockwise: true,
    sort: undefined,
    animate: false,
    animationDuration: 500,
    ready: undefined,
    stop: undefined
  },


  // interaction options:
  zoomingEnabled: false,
  userZoomingEnabled: false,
  panningEnabled: false,
  userPanningEnabled: false,
  boxSelectionEnabled: false,
  selectionType: 'single',
  touchTapThreshold: 8,
  desktopTapThreshold: 4,
  autolock: false,
  autoungrabify: false,
  autounselectify: false,
});
});
```

There is a way to control the size of the edges forcing a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the circle layout on the outside nodes only, specifying your radius as desired and the bounding box centred around the centre node.  Run whatever layout you like on the other nodes after init, so you have initial positions to base the secondary layouts on.

http://js.cytoscape.org/#collection/layout

Comment: hat's the way. I forced positions based on a fixed radius, than I plot the nodes around center node with sine, cosine and a fixed angle constant, solved it!